# After I do Mutable LiveData.asFlow in viewModel - LiveData.observe did not work

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines

In view model, I do:

```
 suspend fun waitResponseCode(): Integer? {
    responseCodeMld.asFlow().take(1).collect {
        responseCode = (it)
        Log.d("RsLog", "Now is responseCode $responseCode")
    }
    if (responseCode != null) {
        if (validateManager.onValidate(responseCode!!.toInt())) {
            cookieManager.saveCookie(getAuthData.getCookieData())
            isLoginMLD.value = true
        } else isLoginMLD.value = false
    }
    return responseCode
}
```

But, when I try to observe this livedata in fragment, my observer doesn't work, it receives nothing:

```
viewModel.responseCodeMld.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { Log.d("RsLog",viewModel.responseCodeMld.value.toString()) })e here
```

Comment: do I read it correctly that `responseCodeMld` is MutableLiveData? If that's the case why use flow and not just LiveData without additional conversion?

Comment: Yes, you are right, but i study Corutines, and i want to apply them.

Comment: ok, in that case I think you should skip the MutableLiveData completely, and use Flow in the first place. Then the viewmodel would observe this `viewModel.responseCodeFlow.asLiveData().observe(...`